# Solve implication using laws

Tags: equivalence-relations

**(~p V ~q) V (~p V q)**

I tried to solve above equivalence like below

**(~p V ~p) V (q V ~q)**

but is there any law to get this or is it law if it is what is that law.

Comment: Homological algebra???

Comment: @WillO No this is a logical equivalence problem but I couldn't find a tag for this question sorry about that.